# Win32 C++: How to print a smily face ☻ onto console output stream?

Tags: c++

I tried setlocale, wchar, usual char... how to define:

```
char c = '☻'
cout << c << endl;
```

to print onto console anething (this is relevant to VS2012 and http://ideone.com/LJtDUz)

Comment: Y u no print _:)_ instead? :v

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815397/console-outputs-smiley-face

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that windows by default does not handle Unicode characters and the windows console is not able to display them.

A solution I found at [This CPP Thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/95308/) is as follows:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    wchar_t* c = L"☻"; /* needed because the project is using 'Unicode Character Set' */

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT); /* set stdout to UTF16 */
    std::wcout << c << std::endl; /* use a wide cout call to output characters */

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

When you try and use the `☻` symbol directly in your code, windows will tell you that i needs to convert your files to `Unicode`, make sure to accept that and use `Unicode Character Set` as your projects character set type.

Comment: Surprised that works. VS silently swap ansi for unicode for chars?

Comment: @user4581301 Honestly I'm not 100% happy this answer explains everything (even though it is correct), so i'm looking up what exactly is happening in the depths right now.

Comment: "sequence \x002 is the unicode representation of the smiley face". No it's not. It's a control character that the original IBM PC happened to display as a smiley face back in 1980s before Unicode was ever invented. Microsoft OSes continue to emulate it to this very day. It has nothing to do with the Unicode character ☻.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the comment you are correct, I will delete that part of the answer. I have come across an actual answer which I will post shortly.