# Int to Byte in C++

Tags: c++, ascii

I am trying to convert int to bytes in c++.I am getting the output in [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) format.  In [console outputs smiley face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815397/console-outputs-smiley-face)
the problem is of smiley face is solved. This solution of single quotes around char variable works for single digit integers only.

Can you please tell me how to handle more than single digit numbers.

The code I am using is below:

```
int main()
{   
int i=32;
int a = '2'; //what to do if I wanted say 12 in bytes and not in CP437 or ASCII
string z ;
vector<unsigned char> arrayOfByte (4);
while(i!=0)
   {
    arrayOfByte[i] = (a>> (i));
    z = arrayOfByte[i];
    cout<<z<<endl;
    i = i-8;
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
```

Comment: To store the integer value 12 in a byte: `unsigned char x = 12;` Is that what you are asking? If you want to store the string `"12"`, you can't do that in 1 byte.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you want to do, but the way to store multiple bytes is in an array of `unsigned char` and the way to store a number is without single quotes.

Comment: `a >> 32` will cause undeifned behaviour (if you have 32-bit ints) and also `arrayOfByte[32]` is out of bounds of a 4-byte vector. You need to rethink that loop

Comment: I need to convert python built-in function to_bytes to C++.This is different from getting the hex value of the number. Moreover if I don't put quotes I get smiley face where what I want is 2. I am not sure what is the name of the format of result to_bytes (python built-in) function but it is neither ASCII nor hex.